# partial derivatives of multivariable functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
 f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^3 + xy^2 + 4 z
 D[f[x, y, z], x]
```

gives the result 
     2 x + 6 x^5
which is obviously wrong. What could be wrong with my code?

also if I try

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^3 + x*y^2 + 4 z
D[f[x, y, z], x]
```

the ansewer is another wrong

```
2 x + 5 x^4 + 6 x^5
```

is my error syntax?
thanks

Comment: Restart the kernel. Something is going wrong here; maybe a hanging definition of `y` or `z`. Morever `xy^2` should probably be `x y^2`...

Comment: the most likely explanation is that you defined `y=x^2` and `z=0` somewhere before. Use `Clear[x,y,z]` and try your second code again.

Comment: In addition, as you may already have noticed, `xy^2` is the square of the variable `xy`, rather than `x`times the squared `y`. You need to either write `x*y^2`, or `x y^2`, according to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

Both of those functions work normally on my computer. As @halirutan has suspected, the reason seems to be that you have made some definitions on y and z, thus giving the wrong result. [image]